# Issue saving user object to Firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Im using the firebase authentication function which returns a user object as follows:

```
auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(user => {
```

Im then trying to save this user object to the Firebase database like so

```
database()
        .ref('profiles/users/' + user.user.uid)
        .set({
          myUserObj: user,
        })
```

However firebase database is returning an error `'Cannot read property 'code' of undefined'`  FULL CODE BELOW

```
auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(user => {
      console.log(user.user);
      database()
        .ref('profiles/users/' + user.user.uid)
        .set({
          myUserObj: user,
        })
        .catch(err =>
          console.log(err.message),
        );
    })
```

Comment: How are you able to tell that the error is coming from the code you've shown here?

Comment: theres a catch statement on the database .set method

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the full code that illustrates the error, and be clear about how it's executing from your perspective?  Please read this if you haven't already:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database can only store valid JSON objects. The [`UserCredential` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential) contains many methods, which makes it not a valid JSON object.

You could give it a try to save it with:

```
  database()
    .ref('profiles/users/' + user.user.uid)
    .set({
      myUserObj: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)),
    })
```

If this doesn't work, you'll have to explicitly name the properties that you want to save.

Comment: Hey James. Did you give this a try? Did it work? If not, what was the problem after this change?

Comment: Its actually one of the functions of the user object I want to store.  

App requires user to validate email in order to unlock functionality.  If they try to use functionality and they have not yet validated email.....I use the function user.sendEmailVerification().  However I need to somehow persist this function if I am to use when user hits that part of the user journey.

Perhaps theres a better way for me to persist the user.sendEmailVerification() function than Firebase?

Comment: p.s. your solution does allow storage of the regular objects nested in UserCredential parent object...however the functions (that I am needing) are lost

Comment: As said: the Firebase Realtime Database can only store JSON objects, which means it can't store functions. The approach in my answer will persist their email verifications state, but not the function.

Comment: Aside from that though I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, and this by now sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's the purpose of storing the User object? What do you intend to do with the data once you reload it from the database? If for example you want to restore the User object when the web page reloads, you can use the approach in the first snippet shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: OMG thats exactly what I need!!  firebase.auth().currentUser.  So simple; THANK YOU